# Storing static table data as a collection in myBatis

Tags: select, mybatis, static-data

I am using myBatis for my ORM frameowrk.I need to load the data of a static table(for eg country table) into memory and be able to use whenever needed by other business objects.Is there any effective way to carry out this in myBatis ?

Comment: Have you take a look at mybatis caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add [`<cache/>`](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#cache) element to mapping.